# How to get access token when using functional testing symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I would like to add a access token in my functional test

```
public function testShowEmployees(){

        $accessToken = "";
        $this->client->request('GET', 'api/v1/patients/108', array(),
            array(),
            array('CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json',
                'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' => "Bearer {$accessToken}",);

        $this->assertEquals(
            Response::HTTP_OK,
            $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode()
        );

        $this->logIn();

        $this->client->request('GET', 'api/v1/patients');
        $client = static::createClient();
}
```

I try to search in google but I failed to find concrete example for getting the access token. I have this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253376/symfony-2-controller-test-cant-pass-authorization-header) but there is no clue there how i can get the token. but if i try this one

```
$client->getContainer()->get('security.context')->getToken();
```

I get an error

```
You have requested a non-existent service "security.context"
```

**UPdate**

in my controller test I have these codes

```
public function setUp()
    {
        $this->client = static::createClient( array(),
            array(
                'PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'sample',
                'PHP_AUTH_PW' => 'sample'
            ));

    }

    public function testShowEmployees(){

        $accessToken = "";
        $this->client->request('GET', 'api/v1/patients/108', array(),
            array(),
            array('CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json',
                'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' => "Bearer {$accessToken}"));

         echo $this->client->getContainer()->get('security.token_storage')->getToken();
        die;
}
```

when I run the phpunit command. I get empty result from token I echo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You have requested a non-existent service "security.context"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36531853/you-have-requested-a-non-existent-service-security-context)

Comment: Have you even Googled this error message?

Comment: @StephanVierkant yes. the link you give. give an error. Call to a member function get() on null

Comment: You should read the answer, try to understand it and modify the answer to your specific needs. Just copy-paste won't help you.
Please read the first sentence before copy-pasting the code.

Comment: Ok. I update my post

Comment: I think you just solved your problem (non-existent service "security.context") by replacing it by `security.token_storage` isn't it? If you've got an other problem now, please open a new question.