# PHPUnit - getallheaders not work

Tags: api, http-headers, phpunit

I'm testing my code, and i have some problem with header. In each api i use

```
$headers = getallheaders();
```

to get that, and this works fine when i test with the app or crhome postman extension.
When i lauch my test, like this

```
 $client = $this->createClient();
    $client->request('GET', '/api/shotcard',
        ['qrcode'=>'D0m1c173'], [],
        ['HTTP_API_TOKEN' => 'abc123']
    );

    $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
```

where i try to shot a card with that qrcode with a user with that test token (not the token i'll use in the application), i see a call like this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11681422/5475228 .
The test fails in this way:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function AppBackendBundle\Controller\getallheaders() in /var/www/pitstop/src/AppBackendBundle/Controller/ApiController.php on line 42

Comment: from the doc: This function is an alias for apache_request_headers(). Please read the apache_request_headers() documentation for more information on how this function works. http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php

Comment: which version of php are you using? it should be available form the CLI  since PHP 5.5.7

Answer (score 53, accepted):

From [this](https://www.popmartian.com/tipsntricks/2015/07/14/howto-use-php-getallheaders-under-fastcgi-php-fpm-nginx-etc/) article:

> If you use Nginx, PHP-FPM or any other FastCGI method of running PHP
>   you’ve probably noticed that the function `getallheaders()` does not
>   exist. There are many creative workarounds in the wild, but PHP offers
>   two very nice features to ease your pain.

From user contributed comments at `getallheaders()` function on PHP manual by [joyview at gmail dot com](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php#84262)

```
if (!function_exists('getallheaders')) {
    function getallheaders() {
    $headers = [];
    foreach ($_SERVER as $name => $value) {
        if (substr($name, 0, 5) == 'HTTP_') {
            $headers[str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_', ' ', substr($name, 5)))))] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $headers;
    }
}
```

Comment: I also use this solution, and works fine when i test from app or postman. But with PHPUnit dont, I tried also to print the headers, PHPUnit print a empty value. I'm using php 5.5.9

Comment: Unfortunately, this only recognizes headers prefixed with `HTTP_`. Headers like `Accept`, `User-Agent`, and any custom HTTP headers will not be retrieved by this implementation.

Comment: yes @OndřejBouda but you can implements the behaviour adding an `else` statement I suppose

Comment: @Matteo Sorry for wrong comment, `$_SERVER` actually *contains* `Accept` and `User-Agent`. However, as regards to custom HTTP headers, these may not be retrieved this way. The variable `$_SERVER` only contains several standard HTTP headers, as [documented](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), compared to `getallheaders()`, which returns all headers sent by the client.

Comment: Hi @OndřejBouda the `HTTP_` trick is about of  the `BrowserKit` implementation, as example described [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5074):  `headers are also part of $_SERVER, by prefixing them with HTTP_`

Comment: @Matteo Thanks for sharing the link. It appears that only custom HTTP headers _prefixed with `X-`_ make their way to the `$_SERVER` variable. **Without the `X-` prefix, they cannot be retrieved this way.** Unfortunately, this is not documented on the [`$_SERVER` page](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) so I can only tell from observing the specific PHP implementation I currently use (PHP 7.2.6 on Apache 2.4).
Note that custom HTTP headers are _discouraged_ from being prefixed with `X-` so that's somewhat inconsistent of PHP.

Answer (score 4):

i resolve in that way(thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/11681422/5475228)

```
private function request_headers($type, Request $request)
{
    if(function_exists("getallheaders"))
    {
        if($header = getallheaders()[$type])
        {
            return $header;
        }
    }

    return $request->headers->get($type);
}
```

so the normal request from app get header with getallheaders(), the request from PHPUnit get it from Request object. I don't know why (if someone can explain) but works.

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation from @Matteos code which removes Mod-Rewrite and adds in Content-Length and Content-Type which are normally returned by `getallheaders()`. Interestingly, the case of the array keys returned by `getallheaders()` seems to be all over the place and not consistent whereas obviously this version ensures consistency.

```
$allHeaders = array();
foreach($_SERVER as $name => $value) {
    if($name != 'HTTP_MOD_REWRITE' && (substr($name, 0, 5) == 'HTTP_' || $name == 'CONTENT_LENGTH' || $name == 'CONTENT_TYPE')) {
        $name = str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_', ' ', str_replace('HTTP_', '', $name)))));
        $allHeaders[$name] = $value;
    }
}
```